# Any way to search for new domain names privately?

Tags: domain-name

Is there any way to look up the availability of a domain name without risking it being reserved or registered by someone else who is snooping domain name look ups?

Comment: How would they know that you're looking up the availability of a particular domain name?

Comment: I guess I should have done a better google on this question first. This is a good article I just found: http://blog.domaintools.com/2007/03/stealing-domain-name-research/

Comment: @Paul, that really is a good article. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the asker's question is much simpler than what most people seem to be reading.  He is concerned, rightly so, that some domain name lookup services will gladly accept your request for a domain name search, and then a day or two later, the same search will show that the domain name has "coincidentally" been registered.

My advice, if you're serious about wanting a particular domain name, is to not even check on its availability unless you're also willing to drop a few bucks to immediately register it, at least for a short term.  That way if you find that it's available you can immediately register it for relatively cheap and you've bought yourself a year (or however long you decide) to act upon it. (Given that the domain namespace is so crowded it's probably best to have a few candidates in mind.)

Comment: Well worded answer.

Comment: well a domain name lookup service that captures your search and sells it to someone who then registers the domain name isn't really snooping then, is it. if you're using their lookup service, they're not snooping on you, they're capturing the information that you are willingly typing into their search tool. there's a diiference between a lookup service selling info about my search and someone "snoopng" my search.

Comment: Sorry, @joeqwerty, call it what you like, but I think @Paul's question and subsequent article show that this is pretty much what he was asking about.  He wasn't asking about some middleman sniffing router traffic looking for people issuing domain name searches.

Comment: @jmd: That could be the case, but the op stated that he was worried about someone snooping his lookups and i took that to mean a snooper, not a registrar selling his search info to someone else. i can only interpret the question the way it's asked. i can't interpret the intention behind the question. if i ask for something blue should you interpret that i really want something green?

Comment: @jmd: also, no offense intended. i addressed the question i thought was being asked.

Comment: Really? There is no answer that can be worded as "Domain lookup service X can be trusted"

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy or a VPN. That way, they can't find out anything unless you give it to them.

Comment: What does this have to do with looking up domain names?

Comment: @soandos: `privately`

Comment: @TomWijsman, but someone is look at the name, the other person who has access to those access logs does not care who it really, they only care that someone is interested.

Comment: @soandos: It guarantees another connection altogether, there's not any more you can do.